# How to echo usable php code from database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a settings page in my Wordpress Admin Panel where I save some HTML code(with some PHP code in it) as a Wordpress Option, using update_option.

In phpmyadmin, the value is stored exactly like this:

```
<img src = \"<?php bloginfo(\'template_directory\'); ?>/images/flexslider/phone.png\">
```

It works perfect until I try to actually make the code work in a page. I'm printing it like this:

```
<?php echo urldecode(get_option('wp_slider_code')); ?>
```

This, unfortunately, prints the PHP code as it was HTML code. So the PHP code doesn't actually get executed; it's treated like a text, the url becoming:

```
<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/flexslider/phone.png
```

What can I do to make this PHP code get executed when I echo it on a page?

Comment: why don't you run php code first before saving the value to database, so its the url that is save on database and not the php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `eval()` built-in function:

```
eval( $YourString );
```

(Edit:) If `$YourString` return a result, to cath the result you have to use:

```
$result = eval( $YourString );
```

#### Please note:

> **Caution**
>   The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Read mor on [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/eval).